# Prove that $F$ is holomorphic on $D.$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing

> Let $D \subseteq \Bbb C$ be a domain in the complex plane and let $f \in \mathcal H(D).$ Define a function $F : D \longrightarrow \Bbb C$ by $$
> F(z) = \left\{
>         \begin{array}{ll}
>             \dfrac {f(z) - f(a)} {z-a} & \quad z \neq a \\
>             f'(a) & \quad z=a
>         \end{array}
>     \right.
> $$ Prove that $F$ is holomorphic on $D$ i.e. $F \in \mathcal H (D).$

It is clear that $F \in \mathcal H \left (D \setminus \{a \} \right)$ and $F$ is continuous on $D.$ I know that this is happening due to **Riemann's Removable Singularity Theorem**. But this result has appeared much before the concept of **Singularity** in the book I am following. This result appeared even before **Cauchy's Integral Formula for Derivatives**. In fact this result leads to **Cauchy's Integral Formula** for simply connected domains. Is there any independent way of proving it without using those theorems that I mentioned? Any suggestion regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know Morera's theorem? Power series expansions of holomorphic functions?

Comment: @DanielFischer I have heard of Morera's theorem and power series expansion of holomorphic function but I haven't read them yet. Those theorems are appearing after **Cauchy's Integral Formula** in the book I am following. Can $F$ be proved holomorphic at $a$ in an elementary way? What I need only to show that $F$ is complex differentiable at $a.$ Am I right sir?

Comment: Yes, complex differentiability at $a$ is the point to prove. That is easier if you have more things you can use. What sort of things have you at your disposal?

Comment: @DanielFischer I want to mean that can I show the existence of the limit $$\lim\limits_{z \to a} \frac {F(z) - F(a)} {z-a} = \lim\limits_{z \to a} \frac {\frac {f(z)-f(a)} {z-a} -f'(a)} {z-a}$$ in an elementary way?

Comment: I know **Cauchy's theorem for disk**, **Goursat's theorem for Rectangle**, **Cauchy's theorem for Simply Connected Domains**, **Index Number**, **Cauchy's Integral formula** etc.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Morera's theorem and the power series expansion of holomorphic functions both depend on Cauchy's integral formula, so if we're not allowed to use the formula, then we also aren't allowed to use those theorems.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos But the simple version considering only integrals over a circle suffices. That's often done early, so I ask.

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: I'm using second edition of the book **Foundations of Complex Analysis** written by S.Ponnusamy (**Narosa Publishing House**) @Matematleta.